Is there a better way to handle close exceptions in a java try-with-resources close
With try-with-resources, we are guaranteed the resources will be closed, but if there is also a catch on the try, that catch will get either of the exceptions from the try block or the close() of the resources, (or both, with resources suppressed).  We may want to very different things if the main try block succeeds and the resource close() fails. However, there's not a good way to differentiate those cases in the catch.   I've found a workaround (simplified here):
public class TryExample  implements Closeable {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println("----- START -------");
        System.out.println("Results: ====================== " + readString());
        System.out.println("----- END -------");
    }

    static String readString() {
        String result = null;
        try (TryExample example = new TryExample()){
            result = example.read();
            return result;
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            if (result != null) {
                System.err.println("Must have gotten an exception closing: " + e.getMessage());
                return result;
            }
            else {
                System.err.println("Must have gotten an exception reading: " + e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    
    public String read() throws IOException {
        //return "SOME READ RESULT";
        throw new IOException("EXCEPTION: ------- Some read exception");
    }
    public void close() throws IOException  {
        //throw new IOException("EXCEPTION: ------- Some close exception");
    }
    
}

Uncomment the return/throws for different cases.
Basically, it just uses the result to differentiate between an exception in the try block vs an exception in the resource close. (The solution could be generalized by wrapping the result so a null value could be a valid return value.)
This feels very clunky, but I've not found a cleaner solution.  Is there a better way to do this? It seems that having catch handle both for the try block and for the resource close() is problematic, especially given that Closable implementations are typically going to have methods used within the try block that also potentially throw IOException.
So, is there a more straightforward way to express this now that try-with-resources has been around for a while? (Currently using Java 21.)
Thank you in advance.
UPDATE: This question was closed and indicated that it was a duplicate.  However, the link provided:
Catch errors during object construction from try-with-resources separately from body  references a question for the construction of a resource, not the close() of that resource.  Both the title of my question and that of the provided title explicitly state their respective use:  "close exceptions in a java try-with-resources close" vs "Catch errors during object construction".

I think Oracle's Java Tutorial explains it well. Note that there are suppressed exceptions and not suppressed resources - as you stated in your question - and you can retrieve the suppressed exceptions via method getSuppressed in class java.lang.Throwable. So couldn't you handle the exception based on whether there are suppressed exceptions or not?

@Abra, if no exception is thrown by the try block, but one is thrown by the close(), then there are no suppressed exceptions.  It is just thrown. But since read() and close() both throw IOException, you can't differentiate from just that.  The Java Tutorial doesn't address this, afaict.   Re: "suppressed resources": Yes, I was being overly brief when I said:  "... (or both, with resources suppressed)", I meant with the exceptions from the close of the resource(s) suppressed. Sorry for any confusion.


We may want to very different things if the main try block succeeds and the resource close() fails.

You've drawn that conclusion too hastily. It is, almost always, incorrect.
What meaningful difference is there?
I am writing data
If the distinction you are looking for is to differentiate between a write call causing an exception and a close() call, that is wrong. There is no meaningful distinction in semantics. It is incorrect to conclude that the data you 'sent' (via write) has actually 'arrived' (e.g. has actually appeared on disk). output resources buffer. Almost all of them do. Hence, write calls can succeed (because you're just moving bits into a different part of memory somewhere), even if they are never going to actually get there: If write(someBytes) returns without error that does NOT mean the bytes have fully made it to the other side. In case you doubt this, simply refer to BufferedOutputStream. Its one and only job is literally to convert the majority of write() calls into pure memory blitting operations!
Hence, there are no good reasons to attempt to differentiate, and, indeed, the 2 methods (close() and write()) share virtually 100% overlap causes for exceptions and the messages that convey them. write() can fail due to disk full. close() can fail to disk full. If close() throws, you must assume that some preceding write() would have failed with that exact exception if only the buffer sizes were a little smaller. Hence, essentially by definition of the exception behaviour of close v. flush, caring about whether close() threw it, or write() threw it, is necessarily a bug.
We can recreate this easily:
var fos = new FileOutputStream("/mount/usb-stick/test.txt");
var out = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
System.out.println("Yank the stick out now...");
Thread.sleep(10000);
out.write(1); // write one byte.
System.out.println("No exception? How did we get here??");
out.close(); // HERE, exception occurs

I am reading
This one is a lot more nuanced. The general theory is that if all your read() ops succeed, you have reached the end of the file by way of receiving -1 from your last read() call, then - so what. if the close() call fails, that's immaterial and should therefore be handled differently (generally, by ignoring it completely).
But this isn't a useful distinction. Because this never happens. There are 2 exceedingly exotic scenarios that don't happen that you're trying to cater to:

read() was lying to you; it returned -1, yes, but the underlying resource, whatever it might have been, is just wonkily set up. The read call doesn't realize an error has in fact occurred, and instead returns -1, but close() (which, usually, is far less optimized; you call read() a lot more than close, after all!) does some extra legwork and determines properly that reading has, in fact, failed. The same principle applies - you should definitely not ignore that exception, nor deal with it differently.

close()'s exception is lying to you and read() was not: For whatever reason, closing really is failing, but you have fully read the entire resource. This.. doesn't happen. Or at least, it is extremely rare.


Hence, you might find that first case (read() lies!) so rare that you wash your hands of it and, if it ever occurs, will simply blame the implementors of the underlying resource for messing up their read() impl. However, that second case is even more rare.
See also this 2012 bug report about removing closeQuietly from guava - which explains also from the point of view of the guava team why they have, indeed, removed that method from guava entirely (in case your primary intent of 'I want to handle exceptions in close() differently' boiled down to '... I want to ignore them').

As I indicated, I was considering a read(). However, I'm looking for a general approach for any Autocloseable. The point is, you can't tell the difference between an some operation and the close() failing.  To say, "this doesn't happen" assumes a lot about the nature of the Closable. Given that the Autocloseable API explicitly provide for that possibility, I'd rather have a solution that accounts for it, if reasonably possible.  If something does go wrong, then assuming the exception was due to a completed unit of work could result in unnecessary failures.

The reason the closable API allows it, is specifically this - that close() can throw, but if it does, it is to be taken as 'well, the most recent read() would probably have thrown that'. Still the same principle at work: You should not treat them differently.

Can you point me to something in the documentation for Autocloseable that states that?  I did find: "While this interface method is declared to throw {@code Exception}, implementers are strongly encouraged to
declare concrete implementations of the {@code close} method to
throw more specific exceptions, or to throw no exception at all if the close operation cannot fail."

Nowhere, Closable is extremely abstract, it doesn't add handcuffs that aren't necessary for its operation. To be clear, your request is not "100% of the time incorrect", just, in 99% of them. If you insist on an answer, it fits in this comment and probably isn't what you wanted to hear: There is no nice way at all, use an old style try/finally with a ton of boilerplate.

Specifically: Network, well, anything? The 'rule' (handling exceptions from close() differently vs. the last read/write call would be wrong) applies. File stuff? Applies. The various filters in the JDK such as BufferedOutputStream? None of them modify the status of whether the rule applies (i.e. wrapping a thing that applies to the rule means the rule applies to the wrapped thing too). compressors? Rule applies.

The rule applies mostly, but not quite so black-and-white, for crypting and hashing schemes. Some hypothetical 'I just pass data right on through, but specifically in close(), I check if all the bytes hash up to a pre-set value and if they do not, close(), and only close(), throws some exception indicating hash failure, for example. I still have a hard time imagining what you would want to do differently, though. Other than 'how to convey the error to the user', but that doesn't count (the exception caught has that job, not which thing threw it).

Which immediately gets us to the second point which I wonder I should add to the answer: Even if close() throws meaningfully different things, so what? The exception object you caught will tell you. If the exact same exception object can be thrown by either write() or close() and you want to handle it differently even if they are identical, the advice is: Fix the crappy API then. Not 'find a lang construct that makes it easy to tell which call threw it'.
